# Start with Debugging fails after upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 17.8.1

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, visual-studio-2022

Getting error message: Unable to attach CoreCLR. "operation not supported"
when I try and debug my C# program on my ARM Raspberry Pi Model 3B which is running Windows IoT (old version of it that was made to work on the 3B).

If I run the code instead of debug there's no issue, runs fine.

This has started occurring after I let VS 2022 update itself the other day.
Searching for this error I find various same error message reports that we're related to upgrading from .NET5 to .NET6 some time ago where the solution is to turn off the  setting. But in my case this isn't related to .Net and I can see no PublishSingleFile setting in the project.

Can anyone offer any ideas as to what might be the cause as its got me baffled?

Update - issue remains after upgrading VS to 17.8.4
Unable to find a reason for the issue or solution, ended up solving by opening the project and debugging with VS2019. I'd used it previously to VS2022, but VS2022 had been fine up until this recent update :-(

Comment: Are you remote-debugging on the PI or is everything running on it?

Comment: Have you tried to further update to 17.8.1?

Answer (score -2):

You can first try to use Visual Studio Installer to update Visual Studio to the latest version or repair Visual Studio. If this still doesn't work try the following:

**Method 1**: Please turn off all anti-virus software

**Method 2**: Try to change the target framework of the project to .net 7.0 or .net 6.0

**Method 3**:

Control Panel=>System and Security=>Administrative Tools=>Local Security Policy

In the Policy column, double-click Network Access: Sharing and Security Model for Local Accounts.

In the Network Access: Sharing and Security Model for Local Accounts dialog box, change the local security setting to Classic and click OK.

Changing the security model to "Legacy" may result in unexpected access to shared files and DCOM components. If you make this change, remote users can authenticate using your local user account (instead of "guest"). If a remote user matches your username and password, that user will be able to access any folders or DCOM objects that you have shared externally. If you use this security model, make sure that all user accounts on the computer have strong passwords or set up separate network islands for the computers you are debugging or have debugged to prevent unauthorized access.

**In addition**, if you created this project using account A before Visual Studio was updated, and then logged in to account B to debug the project after the update, this issue may also occur.

If the above method does not work for you, will this issue occur when you use Visual Studio to debug any .net 6.0 program after the update?

Comment: Thanks but this is an ARM target project, it runs on Windows IoT on the Raspberry Pi. There doesn't appear to be any issue with the VS install. It also worked perfect for years over many versions of VS prior to this most recent update